# how to insert multiple rows from array values with input

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have my table named i_table with columns:

```
id   name    req_qty  req_date     rcv_qty   rec_date
1    metal   1        2014-03-04
2    spring  5        2014-03-04
```

in my html/php:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<?php $resource2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM i_table",$con);
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($resource2))
        { 
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $result2['id'];?>"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $result2['name'];?>"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="rcv[]" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="date" name="rcv_date[]" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

</table>


<?php };?>

</form>
```

how can I insert in multiple arrays from an input according to their unique ID from db? pls help me here... huhu

Comment: Add the `id` as the key -> `name="id[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]"`,`name="name[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]"`, `name="rcv[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]"`,`name="rcv_date[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]"`. Then on post, using `foreach()` you can get the key `id`.

Comment: how can i do that? how to for each? please help... still learning php

Comment: Can u do a sample for for each sir? So I can follow? pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your form, add the `id` as the key -

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<?php $resource2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM i_table",$con);
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($resource2))
        { 
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="id[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $result2['id'];?>"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $result2['name'];?>"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="text" name="rcv[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<input type="date" name="rcv_date[<?php echo $result2['id'];?>]" value="" />
</td>
</tr>

</table>

<?php };?>

</form>
```

Then on your `insert.php` where you post your form, get the `id` in your foreach -

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $id=>$value){

    $sql = "UPDATE `i_table` SET `name` = '".$_POST['name'][$id]."', `rcv_qty` = '".$_POST['rcv'][$id]."', `rec_date` = '".$_POST['name'][$id]."' WHERE `id` = ".$id."";

    mysql_query($sql,$con);
    }
 }
?>
```

note the `foreach()` is just an example. You will want to sanitize your data before inserting/updating to prevent sql injection. see [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: where do i get the variable $value? where did this came from?

Comment: `$value` is just user defined variable inside a `foreach()` loop (it could also be `$v`, `$x`, `$val`, etc). It might be helpful for you to read the php manual `foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)` - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. I did not use it in my example, but it had to be there so I could access the `$key`, or it would produce a syntax error. Typically you would access/use the `$value` value.